# "rails s" boots thin but cant access via localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I am having difficulty getting rails up and running. I have gotten as far as booting it with the command

```
rails s
```

This results in the following output:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.22.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
installing dummy notifier
Thin web server (v1.7.0 codename Dunder Mifflin)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

When I run localhost:3000

I had the line:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

in my vagrantfile but tried to change this and ran

```
vagrant provision
```

but to no avail. Are there any ways for me to test why I cannot access the project. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Having run the command:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

I received a few errors regarding deprecation and "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation 'capabilities' does not exist"

Would this have anything to do with it not loading correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In your vagrantfile, try to use:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

Comment: Can i then run vagrant provision without any repercussions with my environment

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run `vagrant provision` to change port forwarding, you can just restart the box with `vagrant reload`.

Rails defaults to only binding to localhost, and won't allow connections from other hosts (even a browser on your port-forwarded host). Try starting the rails server binding on all addresses like this:

```
rails s -b 0
```